# Can I have a View as input to a data binding BindingAdapter on Android?

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

I want to establish a relationship between a `ProgressBar` and a `WebView` Something like this in XML:

```
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"/>

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/wvb_webView"
        app:attachedProgressBar="@{@id/progressBar}"/>
```

With this code I can create a `BindingAdapter` to do the wiring like this:

```
@BindingAdapter({"app:attachedProgressBar"})
public static void setAttachedProgressBar(WebView webView, @IdRes int progressBarId) {        
        ProgressBar progBar = (ProgressBar) DataBindingUtil.getBinding(webView).getRoot().findViewById(progressBarId);
        wireStuff(webView, progBar); 
}
```

This works, but it irks me that I have to call `findViewById`. Is there any way I can refactor the XML and the BindingAdapter to take a direct reference to the `ProgressBar` as input instead of the `@IdRes int` ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Instead of id, directly pass `ProgressBar` in your `BindingAdapter`

```
@BindingAdapter({"app:attachedProgressBar"})
public static void setAttachedProgressBar(WebView webView, ProgressBar progBar) {        
    wireStuff(webView, progBar); 
}
```

XML code :

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"/>

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/wvb_webView"
    app:attachedProgressBar="@{progressBar}"/>
```

Comment: I'm then getting this error: "Identifiers must have user defined types from the XML file. progressBar is missing it"

Comment: are you passing your `ProgressBar` id in `app:attachedProgressBar`?

Comment: definitely yes, and it is working. Check it once again, remove all code from `BindingAdapter` method, put some log and check what happens

Comment: Huh, got it working after I removed an underscore from my id. Maybe the data binding framework does some rewriting of naming convention?  `progressBar` works. `wv_progressBar` doesn't. I've been able to reproduce it in a second, clean project as well. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: If it is `wv_progressBar` than you need to pass `wvProgressBar`

Comment: Well of course. See for yourself: "master" branch here does not compile. Checkout branch "fixed" and it compiles . https://github.com/Nilzor/android-databinding-tests . Only change is in activity_main.xml

Comment: yes that is what i am telling it should be `app:attachedProgressBar="@{wvProgressBar}"`. As DataBinding will remove underscores and update variable name in camel case letters.

Comment: Oh I see. Was a bit quick on the trigger there. :)

Comment: thank you. I have the same error, but it fixed by `id` from `content_` to `content`.

Comment: This is a small issue and this works great, but I'm getting a warning that says "View field progressBar collides with a variable or import". Any reason I should worry if this is "safe" or not, or should I ignore that warning?